# Make Levenstein's Distance algorithm fit my needs

Tags: c#, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I am having some trouble with the Levenstein Distance-algorithm.

I am using Levensteins distance algorithm to compare a product name with a list of product names, to find the closest match. However, I need to tweak it a bit. I am using the example from [dotnetperls.com](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein).

Say I have a list A of 2000 product names from my own database. I sell all these products myself.

Then all of a sudden I get a list B from one of my suppliers with product names and a new price for each product. This might happen more than once a year, so I want to develop software to do the work manually.

The problem is that this supplier isn't very good at consistency. So he makes small changes in the names every now and then, which means that I cannot do a simple string comparison.

I have implemented distance algorithm, but it does not really fit my needs. - yet!

While running through my suppliers list, I came across a product called

> American Crew Anti Dandruff Shampoo 250 ml

This product was successfully matched with my own product called

> American Crew Anti-Dandruff 250 ml.

With a distance of 10.

**Problem**

I also came across a product called

> American Crew 3-In-1 Shampoo 450 ml.

Which was mistakenly matched with

> American Crew Daily Shampoo 450 ml.

instead of my

> American Crew 3 in 1 450 ml.

And I can see why! But I am not sure how I should change the algorithm from here.

Any ideas?

By the way, I am not really good with algorithms, but I believe some kind of weighing would help me out here.

**EDIT:**

Computation time isn't really a concern. Even if it takes ten hours to complete, it's still a lot better than doing it manually :P

Comment: Perhaps alter the algorithm to give you a list of the closest 4 or 5 products for ones that don't have an almost exact match. Then you can quickly look through them manually and pick out the right one.

Comment: Yes, I have thought of that as well. This might actually be the best way to do it.

Comment: You could even play around with the algorithm and choose a distance at which you know any further it would be impossible for there to be a correct match (Say 30 or so off the top of my head), and reduce some lists that way. I would guess for most products you would only get 1 or 2 options if you do it that way.

Comment: An alternative: If you can obtain the EAN (bar) code you could try matching on that...
Your problem is with the identity of these items. How do you order your items? Is there any "item number", like #12345?

Comment: @mortb That is not possible, since I have not stroed the EAN numbers. Nice thought though

Comment: I have another idea: levenshtein is about finding incorrect spellings. Are the words in the list correctly spelled? If they are maybe you'd be better off writing an algorithm that counts the words in correct places. First you'd make both strings lower case.  Then you'd split them into word lists. You could start from the left and count the words correctly placed and get one sum then you could go from the right and get another sum. Use the sum that is the closest to the number of words on the sentence. Just a though, nothing I've ever implemneted though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be use multiple methods to search and apply a weight to each of them. I've assumed you have some class `Item` with at least a string `Name` property:

```
double levWeight = 1.0;   // adjust these weights as you see fit
double matchWeight = 1.0;

// add whatever to here you'd like
var splitOn = new[] { ' ', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', '\'', '(', ')', '-' };
Func<string, string[]> split = 
    s => s.Split(splitOn, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var matches =
    from xx in mine
    let xp = split(xx.Name)
    select new {
        Item = xx,
        Matches =
           (from yy in theirs
            let yp = split(yy.Name)

            /* found how many name components match */
            let mm = xp.Intersect(yp, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Count()

            /* find the Levenshtein distance of the two names */
            let ld = LevDist(xx, yy)

            /* weight our two criteria */
            let ww = (matchWeight * mm) + (levWeight / ld)

            /* should match on at least ONE name component */
            where mm > 0
            orderby ww descending
            select yy)
    };
```

When run against the corpus of data you have I receive the following output:

- American Crew Anti Dandruff Shampoo 250 ml

  1. American Crew Anti-Dandruff 250 ml
  2. American Crew Daily Shampoo 450 ml
  3. American Crew 3 in 1 450 ml
- American Crew 3-In-1 Shampoo 450 ml

  1. American Crew 3 in 1 450 ml
  2. American Crew Daily Shampoo 450 ml
  3. American Crew Anti-Dandruff 250 ml

If you had more criteria you would simply add them to the query (inline with the other `let` clauses) and apply some weight to their result.

Other possible applications are *"name components in the same order"*:

```
let or = xp.Zip(yp, (a,b) => String.Compare(a, b, true))
           .TakeWhile(c => c == 0)
           .Count()
```

Comment: I would like to thank you very much. You saved my whole week!

Answer (score 1):

You could combine Levensthein with a second-pass without -, spaces, dots, and a third-pass that count exacts similars words, and a forth-pass based on first different word in product name?

May be you can have a look at neuronal networks? It will take you a long time to create the training database, but it could be an answer too (or a part of an answer).

Comment: I like the idea of adding more passes. Thank you.  Neuronal networks seems a bit overkill for this task though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert some of your external knowledge about the data. For example, in the case you showed, the word "shampoo" is not informative about the product (i.e. it does not add useful information regarding whether two products are similar or not). If you would have removed the word "shampoo" from your data, the method would have worked.

So, one thing you can do is search computationally for words that are very frequent (appear in many words) and remove then from your data, since they are likely to be uninformative for your problem. Then run the algorithm.

A second small tweak would be to use your knowledge regarding the character '-'. This character can be considered similar to the space character ' '. So, substitute any '-' into ' ' before running your algorithm.

In this way you don't have to change the algorithm but still use your knowledge about the problem (I understand you want to avoid changing the algorithm).

Finally, you might want to think about more drastic changes such as not using Levenstein distance or comparing whole words. You do not show your dataset, but Levenstein distance in the form you are currently using would be best if the differences are in a small number of characters (typos for example).

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm does not give you a match but a distance. so in your problem scenario you should compare the distance you get from the two different sentences, the lowest distance is better but still no certain match. I guess the best solution would be to present the user with different product names you think would match based on the algorithm. The user can then make the final choice. But if you do not mind mismatches once in a while your on the right path. Just choose a number for the distance you still consider a match but this will give you a lot of false positives.

Comment: I know it gives me a distance, I just selected the one with the lowest distance. :-)

Comment: And I believe your idea of saving the best possible matches for review is the better option here.